# PyPDF2 won't import

Tags: python, installation, import, pypdf

Hi I'm just getting started with python and trying to get some requisite libraries installed. Using Python 3.4.1 on OS X. I have installed PyPDF2 (with supposed success), yet I cannot seem to use the tools:

```
    sh-3.2# port select --list python
    Available versions for python:
        none
        python25-apple
        python26
        python26-apple
        python27-apple
        python34 (active)
    sh-3.2# pip install PyPDF2
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyPDF2 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Cleaning up...
sh-3.2#
```

...

```
import PyPDF2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyPDF2
ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
>>>
```

Am I missing a step? Or is PyPDF2 not supported in py3.4.1?

Answer (score 4):

**PyPDF2** is compatible with Python 3.4, so that's not the problem.

In which Python version do you have pip installed? Even though you're on `python34`, if pip is installed to a different version it will download libraries to that version.

In any case, you can always install by downloading from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=PyPDF2&version=1.23), then running `setup.py install`.

Still, the only possible explanation I have is that the current Python version you're on does *not* have PyPDF2 installed. See if you can import PyPDF2 from any of the other versions.

Comment: How do we really link the PyPDF2 to a different version of Python? I do have several version of Python installed in my Mac (Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.6 etc.,)

Comment: I usually install using `python3.4 -m pip install PyPDF`. You can change the version of python here, and it will install for the right python version.

Answer (score 4):

You can install **PyPDF2** by using the following command,

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case: pip3 install PyPDF2 with python in /usr/local/bin

```
[tim@axelrod utils] (hotfix/2.3.2)$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    22 10 May  2017 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tim   admin    35  3 May  2017 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tim   admin    42  3 May  2017 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tim   admin    37  3 May  2017 /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tim   admin    44  3 May  2017 /usr/local/bin/python3.6-config -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tim   admin    38  3 May  2017 /usr/local/bin/python3.6m -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3.6m
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tim   admin    45  3 May  2017 /usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config -> ../Cellar/python3/3.6.1/bin/python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tim   wheel  4119  7 Jan  2012 /usr/local/bin/python_count
```