# ImportError: No module name PyPdf2 python 2.7.13 on Windows arcgis subdirectory

Tags: python, arcgis

I have looked various posts about python not getting the installed library. I tried using python -m pip install PyPDF2 to get this library installed but no luck. [image]

Edit: site packages
[image]

Comment: other modules have worked just fine?

Comment: Anything preinstalled with ArcGIS works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pyPDF2 module using windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106380/how-do-i-install-pypdf2-module-using-windows)

Comment: It could be a python path problem - try closing your C:\Python27 term and open it up again.

Comment: also what does this show: import site; site.getsitepackages()

Comment: tried doing that. I am getting the same error again. i will try the next thing you said.

Comment: @JeffCharter I have posted a picture of the output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224260/pypdf2-wont-import

Comment: restart computer? xD

Comment: @Lukas I have tried doing pip install pypdf2

Comment: did you tried 'import pypdf2' lowcase? Did you try install it by downloading from PyPI, then running setup.py install?

Comment: @Lukas Yes. I have.

Comment: Ok when restart computer, manually downloading form PyPi then running setup.py install not helps, try this 
- [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501636/how-to-install-pip3-on-windows)

Comment: not running Linux.....

Comment: try these 2 line in your python terminal 1.import sys
2.sys.path.append('c:\python27\argis10.5\lib\site-packages')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472436/add-a-directory-to-python-sys-path-so-that-its-included-each-time-i-use-python

Comment: @JeffCharter thanks that work except that I had to type in the console as `import PyPDF2` after that. Please put that your comment as answer so I can give you points for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your PyPDF2 module is install inside the arcgis sub-directory
If you add this to the top of your script that should do it

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:\python27\argis10.5\lib\site-packages')
import PyPDF2
```

If you need you can also look into modifying your PYTHONPATH

Edit adding on to Jeff's answer: 
I added a new pythonpath variable in environmental variables that I was missing to direct the python console to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages
[image]