# I have pyPDF2 installed on my interpreter that has venv and uses python 3.6.6 but i'm not able to import it. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pycharm, pypdf

I have pyPDF2 installed on my interpreter that has venv and uses python 3.6.6 but i'm not able to import it. What am I doing wrong? I use pycharm.
[image: IDE wont detect pyPDF2]

[image: But it is clearly installed]

Comment: possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224260/pypdf2-wont-import

Comment: I had gone through that thread before, no solutions there.

Comment: @AakashDusane just because PyCharm doesn't suggest it, the code might still run. Have you tried running it? What precise error do you get? Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> import PyPDF2

Python is case sensitive.

Comment: I've tried that too. Pycharm doesn't even suggest the module 'pyPDF2' in it's drop down while importing which is very strange.

Comment: That's the issue, you're using p instead of P. I can share a screen shot if needed

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. But before I answer that, I have to re-iterate that -
NO, Pycharm wasn't detecting the module even when I tried

```
import pyPDF2
```

> Solution:
>
> Uninstall pyPDF2, re install it, and this time install it through the
>   IDE through that pop-up (refer to example screenshot)
>   [image: screenshot]
>
> I found this weird as I don't usually install modules this way.